# Typescript complains because of a conditional return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why does Typescript in the below scenario not let me return these values? To me, these are obviously of the correct type because of the type guard in the function body.

```
type Container = {
    name: string | number
}

function unpack<T extends Container>(x: T): T["name"] extends string ? "yes" : "no" {
    if (typeof x.name === "string") {
        return "yes"
    }
    return "no"
}
```

But TS tells me `Type '"yes"' is not assignable to type 'T["name"] extends string ? "yes" : "no"'.` and also `Type '"no"' is not assignable to type 'T["name"] extends string ? "yes" : "no"'.`

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIgJygXigbwCgoSoFkBbCALigGdhN0BzKAHzIFcKAjLQgL6FCAM04IAxsFSIo4sMgkBrADwAVKBAAewCAgAmdWIhTosAPgAUW2moCUtgNoAiclWcBdTTr2H6jFigAfihnEAg6ZyhaVzgoolIoVBEoS1BIOBStADo3aBwC0IYmBGZnOwJiRNJMCGBOTARQ8MiqkiFE2vrG0IQ4wSA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently a design limitation or missing feature of TypeScript.  Currently there is no support for "narrowing" [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters (maybe that would mean re-[constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) them) via [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).  There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) asking for something better here so that the compiler could possibly recognize code similar to your example as valid.

---

Currently the compiler treats generic [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) as being essentially *opaque*; it *defers* evaluation until the generic types are specified.  Inside the body of `unpack()`, the type checker just shrugs its proverbial shoulders and says it doesn't know *what* might be assignable to `T["name"] extends string ? "yes" : "no"`, and complains about almost any assignment to that type. It doesn't really try to analyze what you're doing.  You'd think it's easy to figure this out, but it's actually tricky in general.

Consider

```
const result = unpack({ name: Math.random() < 0.999 ? "string" : 123 });
// const result: "no"
console.log(result) // 99.9% "yes", oops
```

It turns out that you can't say that `typeof x.name === "string"` implies that `T` is any narrower than `Container`; it could be that `T` is `Container`.  If so, then `T["name"] extends string` is actually *false*, in which case your return type is `"no"`, but the implementation could well return `"yes"`.  Oops.

You could refactor to use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), which will behave better here:

```
type YesNo<T> = T extends string ? "yes" : "no"
function unpack<T extends Container>(x: T): YesNo<T["name"]> {
    if (typeof x.name === "string") {
        return "yes"
    }
    return "no"
}

const result = unpack({ name: Math.random() < 0.999 ? "string" : 123 });
// const result: "yes" | "no"
console.log(result) // probably "yes", maybe "no", this is okay
```

But the compiler still doesn't see it as properly implemented, because it really has no idea what might be a valid return value.  As I said, it's tricky.  Implementing the kind of generic type analysis that is correct enough to be helpful and performant enough to be acceptable is not trivial.

For now if you want to suppress errors you need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or their equivalent (like a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)) and move on:

```
function unpack<T extends Container>(x: T): YesNo<T["name"]> {
    if (typeof x.name === "string") {
        return "yes" as YesNo<T["name"]> // assert
    }
    return "no" as YesNo<T["name"]> // assert
}
```

recognizing that this lack of errors doesn't actually make anything safer:

```
function unpack<T extends Container>(x: T): YesNo<T["name"]> {
    if (typeof x.name !== "string") { // oops
        return "yes" as YesNo<T["name"]>
    }
    return "no" as YesNo<T["name"]>
}
```

---

Anyway, if you care about this, you might want to show support for microsoft/TypeScript#33912 by giving it a  and getting a hundred of your similarly afflicted friends to do so also (please don't spam them, though), but for now this is just a limitation we have to deal with.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIgJygXigbwCgoSoFkBbCALigGdhN0BzKAHzIFcKAjLQgL6FCAM04IAxsFSIo4sMgkBrADwAVKBAAewCAgAmdWIhTosAPgAUW2moCUtgNoAiclWcBdTTr2H6jFigAfihnEAg6ZyhaVzgoolIoVBEoS1BIOBStADo3aBwC0IYmBGZnOwJiRNJMCGBOTARQ8MiqkiFE2vrG0IQ4wWEJRAYoWrpOABtgXDkEBWVLfDJKGigAWWRgAAtszGQDOApLCpUoAAZsgE5r4KKA0qjaAEYAJgBmKAE7AG5CAHo-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-NVALmTV1D03VwNMQ1jRg814OtIT6PtTj0NdLJclwgBCb133KAhRMBMkKU46NyLDSjqNcxD3IgFCxNUziOlI4Mem7Xj4oEtzbRE1KJMSBMBCAA)

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. You were absolutely right ... I am more interested in why this doesn't work. I also upvoted the GitHub issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the implementation from the function interface:

```typescript
function unpack<T extends Container>(x: T): T["name"] extends string ? "yes" : "no"
function unpack<T extends Container>(x: T): string {
    if (typeof x.name === "string") {
        return "yes"
    }
    return "no"
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIgJygXigbwCgoSoFkBbCALigGdhN0BzKAHzIFcKAjLQgL6FCAM04IAxsFSIo4sMgkBrADwAVKBAAewCAgAmdWIhTosAPgAUW2moCUtgNoAiclWcBdTTr2H6jFigAfihnEAg6ZyhaVzhnUXEpGQQ5BAVldW9dAyN4JDQMTCsbKHtaBiYEViJSKFQRKEtQSDgGrQA6N2gcHtCKlmc7AmJa0kwIYE5MFLCI%20NqhWvHJ6dCEOMFhCUQGMjhcVPSlS3wyShooAAYoATsAbkJthF3wozx5RWPTrtoAcl%20bvcgA)

As jcalz mentioned, it is worth noting that this relies on the user to ensure the implementation matches the type as this method effectively bypasses TypeScript's checks that resulted in the original errors (`Type '"yes"' is not assignable to type...`, etc.)

Comment: I'm interpreting the question as "why is this happening" and not "how can I work around it"?  Also: with this implementation you could change it to `typeof x.name !== "string"` and it wouldn't care.  This might be fine and is about the best we can do, but you should mention it.