# <T extends boolean>

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

`Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? number : number | undefined'.`

I'm trying to create a numerical input from the terminal, and let the user decide if they are required to respond with a number or not. When the user says it is not required, this will return undefined, but typescript returns an error.
Does anyone knows why this error is shown? Here is the code:

```js
export function number<T extends boolean>(props: {
  placeholder?: number;
  message: string;
  required?: T;
}): T extends true ? number : number | undefined {
  if (!props.required) return undefined;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand the question. Some information is missing and idea doesn't make sense for me. Why would you want to "extend boolean"?

Comment: TS doesn't use control flow analysis to narrow generic type parameters (that is, checking `props.required` affects the type of `prop` but not `T` itself) so generic conditional types are notoriously difficult to deal with. It's a missing feature, described at [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure there's an existing question about this somewhere (with the same answer @jcalz gave). That said, it sounds like the real issue may be that you've got a runtime condition (whether a given property is required, determined in some dynamic way), and you're trying to compute it at compile-time. That won't work — you just don't have the information yet.

Comment: (e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73640284/1076640)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid TypeScript is not 'smart enough' to infer the return type from the conditional generic, leaving you with having to assert the return type yourself with the `as` keyword:

```
export function number<T extends boolean>(props: {
  placeholder?: number;
  message: string;
  required?: T;
}): T extends true ? number : number | undefined {
  if (!props.required) return undefined as T extends true ? number : number | undefined;
  return 0;
}
```

I am hoping there is a better solution, but I do not know of any.

Comment: This really helped me solving the problem,, thank you so much.